# Combining duplicate values into 1 row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

please see attached the image (this is the table I am looking at replicated in excel called dbo.StaffDetails)

This row has been duplicated because the surgeon 1 code 127 has been incorrectly input in surgeon1code instead of surgeon2code.. is it possible to write a query that when the SourceID is the same and the surgeon1, surgeon2, surgeon3 codes are not on the same row to actually merge them all? (I hope this makes sense?)

So ideally, the attached image would have the 127 as Surgeon2code instead of being on its own row?

Many thanks for any help with this, I really appreciate it[image]

Comment: is this mysql or sql-server? please fix the tags.

Comment: Sorry, done this now

Comment: Please don't use images for data/code.  [How to post a tsql question on a public forum](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) and [How-to-Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can use grouping. Something like:

```
SELECT SourceID, 
       MIN(Surgeon1Code) AS Surgeon1Code,
       MAX(Surgeon1Code) AS Surgeon2Code,
       MAX(Surgeon1Code) AS Surgeon3Code,
       MAX(Anaesthetist1Code) AS Anaesthetist1Code,
       ....
FROM dbo.StaffDetails
GROUP BY SourceID
```